# How can i get html from a page that has javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

When I load the page I get only a part of the code. The site is http://www.livescore.in 
I want to create an html page that have a variable containing the full html code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `iframe`

Comment: or you can load multiple html files with Ajax

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after. Using jQuery you can load a full page into your site. Create an empty div on your page and use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#yourDivsID").load("yourURLHere");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I do not know if I'm doing something wrong but not work for me

Comment: @user2551814 Have you got the jQuery library linked to your page?

Comment: this is my test:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="AlterVista - Editor HTML"/>
  <title>GOTLINKS</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#div1").load("http://www.livescore.in");
   });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div1"></div>
  
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user2551814 You need to put the full URL into the .load function. Http:// included. And put the script right at the end of the document. Just before your closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the content of an external iframe (i.e an iframe which url belongs to a different domain).

So if your page is at `example.com`, and it contains an iframe loading `livescore.in`, the page will display the iframe and its content but the JavaScript code at example.com cannot read/write the content of the iframe.

There are solutions to this:

1. You can use postMessage to talk to the iframe but that means that the owner of `livescore.in` has agreed to communicate with you.
2. You make an ajax call to a server side script on your domain that will fetch the content for you and send it back to your JavaScript.